# Copy fileShare to another fileShare Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, sdk, fileshare

I can not find the API for Node.js to copy everything in one fileShare to another fileShare in different storage account. Does anyone run into this problem before?

All I can find is the azCopy solution.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> I can not find the API for Node.js to copy everything in one fileShare
>   to another fileShare in different storage account.

This is because no such API exists. [`Node SDK for Azure Storage`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) is a wrapper over [`Azure Storage REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/azure-storage-services-rest-api-reference) and the REST API only supports [`copying files (neither directories nor shares)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-file).

What you would need to do is list all files from a share and then copy these files individually which is what azcopy does.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is the only way to go.